# Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Tags: discussion

Are the predictions on what percentage of the questions in superuser the solution would be to reboot?

I'm going to guess about 5%.

Comment: +1 for the IT crowd reference :)

Comment: My guess is that it is around 50% too *few* answers!! ;)

Comment: Phil Collins reference, I thought

Answer (score 9):

> You cannot fix a machine by just power-cycling it with no understanding of what is going wrong.

Tom Knight

Comment: If you're on a helpdesk, far, FAR too many solutions are "reboot and shut up".

Comment: The rest are usually "Plug the computer in and press the on switch" :p

Comment: Before rebooting you have to waste ***at least*** two and a half hours figuring it out. ***Then*** you reboot.

Comment: I just spent 3-4 hours over a few days troubleshooting a problem, including some Google results of my exact problem in which no less than 4 solutions were provided, one of which seemed to have worked for every other user, but none of them worked for me. Then I rebooted, and the problem went away.

Comment: This is completely incorrect for routers, modems and most smartphones. And even if power-cycling them doesn't solve the problem outright, it at least returns them to a known state where diagnosing the root-cause is much easier.

Comment: "Turn it off and on again" is easier than trying to walk a user through doing things like clearing OS level caches and renewing their DHCP lease... As others have noticed, power cycling is often really effective just because it can quickly rid the system a corrupted in memory state.

Answer (score 7):

can we add an auto bot to add that as the first answer to any question containing keywords such as 'frozen', 'stuck', 'blue screen', etc.

Josh

Comment: Won't be surprised if this Bot achieves Skeet-esque reputation and celebrity in no time

Answer (score 4):

I'm predicting

> Sounds like a virus...my mom had that, I think.

and

> Try control, alt, and delete maybe?

Comment: Yes!! The "virus" thing. How it bothers me. *"My computer is slow even if I purchased and installed AVG, Avast, Kaspersky and SuperAntivirusPlus2013, it must be that Cornflickr thing that's been in the news!"*

Answer (score 4):

You can get some insight into providing true helpdesk-quality answers online by reading [Roy's tech support on Twitter](http://twitter.com/roy_from_it/).

Answer (score 3):

Suggest there is just an automatically posted answer after a 10 second delay suggesting this...

Answer (score 2):

The first two things I ask before anything else are: 
 - Are you in front of the computer?
 - Is it plugged in?

Once I tried to help a user by phone and after half an hour dictating several proceedings, he kindly mentioned he was talking from a public phone in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: You forgot "Is there electricity to the room?" and "Is it smoking, on fire or immersed in water?" ... cause those are both things that happen and don't seem important enough to mention ¬_¬

Answer (score 1):

Try [Tales from the Techs](http://www.techtales.com/tftechs.html) for some true inspiration.